# Timer not stoppinng after StopCoroutine called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, coroutine

I'm unsure why this is happening but I have a countdown timer that fires and is supposed to stop when the user hits a button which calls StopTimerButton(). But even though I call StopCoroutine, the timer keeps counting down until it reaches zero which then calls RestartGame(). What am I missing in my code?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static CountdownTimer countdownTimerInstance = null; // create singleton
    public Object startingScene;
    public GameObject timeOutWarningDialog;
    public float preCountdownLength;
    public float countdownLength;

    private GameObject timerDialogBoxInstance;
    private GameObject timerDialogCountdownText;
    private Text timerDialogCountdownTextTarget;
    private GameObject canvas;
    private IEnumerator warningCounter;
    private IEnumerator preCounter;
    private Button stopCountButton;
    private float countdownInterval = 1.0f;
    private bool preCountActive;
    private bool warningCountActive;

    void Awake()
    {
        ResetCountStates();

        if (countdownTimerInstance == null)
            countdownTimerInstance = this;
        else if (countdownTimerInstance != null)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bool userActive = GameManager.userActive;
        bool onIntroScreen = GameManager.onIntroScreen;

        if (!userActive && !onIntroScreen && !preCountActive)
            StartPreCountTimer(preCountdownLength); 
        else if (userActive && !onIntroScreen && preCountActive)
            StopPreCountTimer();
    }

    void StartPreCountTimer(float length)
    {
        preCountActive = true;
        preCounter = RunTimer(length);
        StartCoroutine(preCounter);
        Debug.Log("PreCount Started");
    }

    void StopPreCountTimer()
    {
        preCountActive = false;
        StopCoroutine(preCounter);
        Debug.Log("PreCount Stopped");
    }

    void WarningDialog(float length)
    {
        preCountActive = false;
        warningCountActive = true;
        canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");
        timerDialogBoxInstance = Instantiate(timeOutWarningDialog); // instantiate timeout warning dialog
        timerDialogBoxInstance.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
        timerDialogBoxInstance.SetActive(true);
        timerDialogCountdownText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CountdownText"); // get reference to countdown text GO
        timerDialogCountdownTextTarget = timerDialogCountdownText.GetComponent<Text>(); // get countdown textfield component
        stopCountButton = timerDialogBoxInstance.GetComponentInChildren<Button>(); // get reference to keep playing button
        stopCountButton.onClick.AddListener(StopTimerButton); // add button listener

        if (warningCountActive && !preCountActive && timerDialogBoxInstance != null)
        {
            warningCounter = RunTimer(length); // create new reference to counter, resets countdown to countdownLength
            StartCoroutine(warningCounter);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RunTimer(float seconds)
    {
        // PRECOUNT TIMER
        if (!warningCountActive)
        {
            float s = seconds;
            while (s > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(countdownInterval);
                s -= countdownInterval;
                Debug.Log("PreCount: " + s);
            }

            if (s == 0)
            {
                preCountActive = false;
                warningCountActive = true;
                WarningDialog(countdownLength);
            }
        }

        // WARNING DIALOG TIMER
        if (warningCountActive)
        {
            float s = seconds;
            while (s > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(countdownInterval);
                if (timerDialogBoxInstance != null)
                    timerDialogCountdownTextTarget.text = s.ToString();
                s -= countdownInterval;
                Debug.Log("WarningCountdown: " + s);
            }

            if (s == 0)
                if (timerDialogBoxInstance != null)
                {
                    StopCoroutine(warningCounter);
                    Destroy(timerDialogBoxInstance);
                    RestartGame();
                }
        }
    }

    void StopTimerButton()
    {
        warningCountActive = false;
        StopCoroutine(warningCounter);

        if (timerDialogBoxInstance != null)
        {    
            Destroy(timerDialogBoxInstance);
            timerDialogBoxInstance = null;
        }
        Debug.Log("Restart Cancelled");
    }

    void ResetCountStates()
    {
        preCountActive = false;
        warningCountActive = false;
    }

    void RestartGame()
    {
        ResetCountStates();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(startingScene.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you calling the `WarningDialog` function?

Comment: I call WarningDialog() after the PreCountTimer reaches zero (in Runtimer).

Comment: And how do you start the timer you want to stop with the `StopTimerButton` function?

Comment: I start the timer in RunTimer with the line: WarningDialog(countdownLength);

Answer (score 0):

Script is too long to figure out the problem but I noticed something that could be the problem.

In your `WarningDialog` function, look at this block of code:

```
if (warningCountActive && !preCountActive && timerDialogBoxInstance != null)
{
    warningCounter = RunTimer(length); // create new reference to counter, resets countdown to countdownLength
    StartCoroutine(warningCounter);
}
```

The `StopTimerButton()` function may not be working because each time the `RunTimer` function is still running and you call the `WarningDialog` function, the coroutine function reference which is named `warningCounter` is lost because it is overwritten when you do `warningCounter = RunTimer(length);`.

You have to move `warningCounter = RunTimer(length);` to the `Start()` function so that `warningCounter` is initialized only **once**.

Comment: Did you try this?